# Tflearn ranking documents with a neural network without softmax output layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tflearn

I have a vanilla feed forward neural network (2 hidden layers and a softmax output layer) that does text classification. It is implemented with tflearn.

What softmax does is that it converts the output to a density probability distribution in order to determine to which one is the most probable class of the input instance.

Instead of classification, I want to rank the documents (each class would have a "score" instead of being a probability). So my approach is not to normalize the output layer and instead I am using only a regular layer (with a sigmoid activation function). This would give me this score (between 0 and 1) of each document.

The model I defined is like this:

```
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    # Build neural network
    net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, x_size])
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, self.HIDDEN_LAYER_SIZE)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, self.HIDDEN_LAYER_SIZE)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, y_size, activation='sigmoid')
    net = tflearn.regression(net)

    # Define model and setup tensorboard
    model = tflearn.DNN(net)
    return model
```

If I train the model with a softmax output, the model is pretty accurate. But if I change the output activation function for a sigmoid, my scores are  not as accurate as I would expect (the score for the right class being the highest). In some cases, the scores are completly wrong.

My questions are: does this approach is correct to do text ranking with a neural network? and why do the scores are not as expected (maybe I am missing something during training or some hyperparameters need some tuning, or do I need more training data with this approach? or is something with tflearn?)

Thanks in advance! 
Ivan

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're trying to solve is a regression problem. You want the result of the network to be a continuous value (in your case, ranging from 0 to 1) instead of mapping it into different categories (which would be called classification).

As a general rule, for regressors you'll want to use **linear activation** (**linear** in tflearn) or ReLU (**relu** in tflearn which ranges from 0 to ∞) for the output layer activation.

The reason your network doesn't perform well with sigmoid activation in the output layer is because of the [vanishing gradient problem](https://ayearofai.com/rohan-4-the-vanishing-gradient-problem-ec68f76ffb9b).
As your output gets near 1, sigmoid gets very, very flat and gradient vanishes to near zero making backpropagation learn rate very slow.

TL;DR: This is normal. It's due to vanishing gradient problem. Use linear or ReLU for regression instead.